# I want integrate php and js for see a video player

Tags: javascript, php, video, jplayer

on this page , at the bottom , I left with the part of the securities and the right side dovre you should open a player , you should open the video corresponding to the title clicked .
Now I can take the path of the video to the title of the db clicked , so :

```
                        <div id="down">

                            <div id="downSx">
                          <?php
ob_start();
$host = "**";
$username2 = "**"; // Mysql username
$password = "**"; // Mysql password 
$db_name = "**"; // Database name

//connect to db
mysql_connect($host, $username2, $password) or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("cannot select DB");


$i=0;
$h=0;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videoMultimedia ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
?>

     <div class="titleSxDown">
         <a class="preset_text" id="<? echo $h++ ?>"><? echo $row[3] ?></a>
     </div>
<?     
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videoMultimedia ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
?>
     <input type="hidden" value="
     <? if($row[1] != ""){
     echo $row[1];
     }else{
     echo $row[2];
     }

     ?>


     " id="link_content_<? echo $i++ ?>" /> 

<?     
}     
mysql_free_result($result);  

ob_end_flush();
?>

</div>

                         <div id="downDx">
                                <div class="descrizioneDxDown">

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                $(document).ready(function() {
                                    $('.preset_text').click(function() {
                                        var target = $(this).attr("id");
                                        $('.descrizioneDxDown').html($('#link_content_' + target).val());
                                    });
                                });
                            </script>
```

I can not but ' to enter the path in this script ( the script is the player ( JPlayer ) ) :

```
                  <script type='text/javascript'>
                      jwplayer('descrizioneDxDown').setup({
                          file: 'pathVideo',
                          image: 'pathIMG',
                          title: 'TITLE',
                          width: '100%',
                          aspectratio: '16:9'
                      });
                  </script>
```

This is the URL of my site: http://www.fifaitaly.altervista.org/index.php

How can I do , help thanks !

Comment: you need to put the `pathVideo` and `pathIMG` amd TITLE etc ?

Comment: I would like the path of the video ... found the method for the video , I think that it is enough to replace raw [ ] .

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: no unfortunately no ... help me please!

Comment: please clearly mention the problem...is the path you can't set or anything else?

Comment: I can not see the player on the right path by inserting a second title on Which you click ...

Answer (score 0):

`jsplayer` takes the `id` ..you are giving `class`

change the class to id:

```
<div id="descrizioneDxDown">  // you are not doing this

</div>
```

Now you have to build a playlist and put it:

```
<script>
    jwplayer("descrizioneDxDown").setup({
      playlist: "/path_to_your_Playlist.rss",
      width: 720,
      height: 270,
      listbar: {
        position: "right",
        size: 240
      }
    });
</script>
```

[Found Here](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1428529-display-a-playlist-sidebar)

Comment: as you can see: http://www.fifaitaly.altervista.org/

Now there is the player, I wish that when you click on the title , open the corresponding video in the player .
As it did before with the path .

how can I do ? And ' this is my problem !

Comment: ciao ciao
eeeeeaaaa
sdfsdfds
fdsfds
dsfdsfdsfds
dsfsd 

is your playlist and it is not playing...is it the problem?

Comment: ciao ciao eeeeeaaaa sdfsdfds fdsfds dsfdsfdsfds dsfsd are the title and each title is a video.
I can render the path in a text (http://www.fifaitaly.altervista.org/test.php) but when I put the player must open the player with the corresponding video, I can not do this thing (http://www.fifaitaly.altervista.org/).

Comment: did you setup a `jwplayer playlist`?  You have setup an youtube video .. by this code `jwplayer('downDx').setup({
                                  file: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-SGACB54YI',
                                  image: 'data:image/jpeg;
                                  title: 'ciaociao',
                                  width: '40%',
                                  aspectratio: '16:9'
                              });`

but no playlist

Comment: yes, but I want to know the code to make sure that you click on a title and opens the corresponding video.

Comment: i dont understand, sorry

Comment: what you not understand? ...you embeded the jplayer from youtube link....now you need to add the playlist with a rss feed...

Comment: no problem where the path is. make the rss file ...as described in the site. and put the files in the path mentioned in the db